# Selecionar dados de uma planilha

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xls

Fiz a leitura de dados de uma planilha utilizando bibliotecas do Python 3 (xlrd / xlsxwriter / Pandas e Numpy). Esta planilha possui nas linhas perguntas da pesquisa e nas colunas as áreas que responderam a pesquisa. Cada frase tem uma nota, que vai de 0 a 100. Preciso criar um código que eu possa selecionar apenas as frases (linhas) com notas menores que 30 por exemplo em todas as áreas (colunas).

Alguém poderia me dar uma dica?

Answer (score 3):

Será que isso pode te ajudar?

```
output = []

    f = open( 'arquivo.csv', 'rU' ) #abrir o arquivo em read universal mode
    for line in f:
        cells = line.split( "," )
        output.append( ( cells[ 0 ], cells[ 1 ], cells[ 3 ] ) ) #Neste caso pegaria a primeira segunda e terceira coluna

    f.close()

    print output
```

Comment: Não ajudou muito. Preciso selecionar dados de um determinado valor (int ou float). No meu problema, cada linha representa uma pergunta da pesquisa, que recebe uma nota de 0 à 100. Em cada coluna tenho as áreas da empresa que responderam a pesquisa. Sendo assim, quero selecionar apenas as menores notas em cada pergunta (linha), ("notas menores que 30 por exemplo"), em relação a cada área (coluna).